# What is wrong with scheme code?

Tags: scheme

i am trying to write a scheme program which will take a list of marks as input and gives the output as a list of the grades.

i got this far , .. i dunno whats wrong i get an error the object () passed as the first argument to cdr is not the correct type  ....

here is the code

```
(define (grades list1)
  (cons (cond ((= (car list1) 100) 'S)
              ((= (car list1) 90) 'A)) 
        (cons (grades (cdr list1)) '())))
```

Comment: Only 3 lines of code, and already the parens are giving me a headache ^^

Comment: @Thomas: Only because the formatting is crap. I'm going to fix it right now. (No matter what language you code in, if someone uses non-standard formatting, it will cause headaches for everyone else who reads it.)

Comment: @Ross: Nice, I see your suggested edit. Standard indentation in Lisp and Scheme code is two spaces, BTW. (All the other places where I had more than two spaces are, of course, for alignment purposes.)

Comment: @Chris, "Standard indentation in Lisp and Scheme code is two spaces" -- chapter and verse, please? Or did you mean somthing like "my preferred indentation" or "the most usual indentation"?

Comment: @Henning: http://mumble.net/~campbell/scheme/style.txt

Comment: That's "somebody's preferences", or at best "somebody's impression of what is common practice", not "standard".

Comment: @Henning: Actually, when it comes to Riastradh and Scheme style, it _is_ as close to standard as you're going to get. In the Scheme world, Riastradh is not just "somebody".

Comment: "As close to standard" does not mean that it _is_ a standard. It just means that "standard" does not apply to this question at all. It's a free-form language; whitespace is not a matter for standardisation here).

Comment: Wow, I didn't intend to start a war on indentation rules... it was only a joke about the abundance of parens in Lisp/Scheme ;)

Comment: @Henning: It's obviously not a standard, of course -- that would mean a language that is sensitive to indentation.  It's "standard" in the sense of being extremely common.  In the same way that putting a newline before a `;` in C is non-standard.  (And since neither of these practices is anywhere close to being in an language standard proper, debating this point more is wasting breath for no good reason.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a base case for your recursion. How do you want your `grades` function to behave when the argument is an empty list? This requires an outer `cond` that tests is the list is empty and returns something appropriate when it is.

Comment: i get your point .. but not able to implement it .. could you please help me with the code .........

Comment: Then it seems you have some language learning ahead of you. This is homework, isn't it? You'll learn nothing by having random people on the internet send you finished solutions that you don't understand.

Comment: not actually homework .... that was asked in an exam ...i have been trying since 2 hours .... but got nowhere

Comment: So you're presently sitting an exam and hoping to use SO to cheat??

Comment: nope the exam was in the morning ... i was just trying to figure out the solution ....

Comment: @angelofdeath: If I were your exam marker, I'd dock all your points for poor formatting, notwithstanding whether the code works or not. :-P

Comment: @angelofdeath: Actually, Henning has helped you as much as he (or anybody else) can help you at the moment. You actually have to understand recursion in order to solve this.

Comment: Recommendation: look at the introductory chapters of http://htdp.org.  In particular, http://htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/curriculum-Z-H-13.html#node_chap_9

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (grades list1)
  (cond((null? list1) `())
       (else(cons (cond ((= (car list1) 100) 'S)
                        ((= (car list1) 90) 'A)) 
                  (grades (cdr list1))))))
```